# How do I find a list (multiset, size n) of integers where the root-mean-square of the set is an integer?

Tags: math, rms

I already found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732555/how-to-find-all-possible-values-of-four-variables-when-squared-sum-to-n)

Brute force is possible of course, but are there any other ways? Is there a way to find all multisets? Is there a way to find out how many combinations exist under a certain limit?

Perhaps this question is too mathy for SO, if that is the case I'll move it.

I created [my own version](https://repl.it/JqY6/83) in javascript by generating all possible combinations of a list of numbers, then checking for integer RMS. These are sets though, not multisets.

Comment: I think it is a little weighty on the mathematics for this site.

Comment: Do you need uniqueness? Finding a multiset is trivial.

Comment: I think you might be better off looking for some Diophantine equation experts on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is range of sum limited?

Comment: @MBo no, not at all, but lets just say we're looking for find_rms_integers(n, r) where n=size of list, and r=chosen rms value

Comment: Do you want to list all multisets, or just count them? Do you want/need to only list/count unique multisets, or do you need to list/count every distinct way of constructing the multiset from the elements provided?

Comment: @Patrick87 ultimately list all multisets, if that would be possible.

Comment: @Michiel I  asked because listing all sets assumes reasonable upper limit, otherwise number of sets becomes huge (perhaps, it rises exponentially)

Comment: @MBo you could assume the function would take as a parameter the goal sum of squares (e.g. 81, example {2,4,5,6})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I used N for sum value and K for the number of squares.

Number of multi-sets grows fast, so N should have reasonable value. So this problem is equivalent to changing sum N by K coins with nominals `1,4,9,25...` (and the number of variants might be calculated using dynamic programming).

The simplest implementation is recursive - we just generate all possible addends. In my Delphi implementation I collect summands in string (instead of list) for simplicity.

Note that such implementation might generate the same sequences again and again - note `{5,7}` end-sequence in my example. To improve performance (important for rather large values of N and K), it is worth to store generated sequences in table or map (with `{N;K;Min}` key). In that case generation from large summands to smaller ones would be better, because small summands give a lot of repeating patterns.

```
procedure FSP(N, K, Minn: Integer; Reslt: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if (K = 0) then begin
    if (N = 0) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Reslt); //yield result
    Exit;
  end;

  i := Minn;
  while (i * i <= N) do begin
    FSP(N - i * i, K - 1, i, Reslt + Format('%d ', [i]));
    i := i + 1;
  end;
end;

procedure FindSquarePartitions(N, K: integer);
begin
  FSP(N, K, 1, '');
end;

 FindSquarePartitions(101, 5);

1 1 1 7 7 
1 1 3 3 9 
1 1 5 5 7 
1 2 4 4 8 
1 5 5 5 5 
2 2 2 5 8 
2 3 4 6 6 
2 4 4 4 7 
3 3 3 5 7
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting